# How can I close Gtk# Window

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I have 2 fullscreen window in my Gtk# application, primary and secondary. I have buttonClose in second form's that click event handler must close this window and make some operation:

```
    protected void OnButtonClose_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some operation

        this.Dispose ();                        
    }
```

But window doesn't close! If I use this code in Primary window, that window will close and application will terminate. Why this code works for primary window and doesn't works for secondary? How can I close secondary window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Window.Destroy() should destroy the window for the secondary window. You could also hide it with .Hide() but not sure that's your intention

Comment: Thanks alot! Window.Destroy() really have helped me

Answer (score 4):

After a ton of research on this I have found what seems to work correctly for me.

```
public WhateverWindow():base (Gtk.WindowType.TopLevel) {
DeleteEvent += delegate { Application.Quit(); };
}
```

try using the `DeleteEvent += delegate { Application.Quit(); };`
in your function see if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
protected void OnBtnCancelarClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Destroy ();
}
```

Comment: This seems not to work: The window closes but the debugger does not terminate. I therefor assume the OnDeleteEvent() handler containing Application.Quit() is not called. If I overwrite OnDestroyed() and invoke Application.Quit() in that context the application is properly terminated. This seems somehow strange: The click on the close symbol at the window results in firing the OnDeleteEvent() but this seems completely unrelated to OnDestroyed() and to some extent to OnDestroyedEvent(). Can s.o. help with this and explain this behaviour? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only method that works as expected is calling:

> RootWindow.Destroy ();

However, ain't sure if that's the right way to do it.